# Trying to get multiple request responses for one callback function

Tags: html, node.js, express

I have a calculator web app using node.js with express. I am trying to make buttons for add, subtract, multiply, and divide. I have a POST request that works when I use only one res.send();, but when I try to make multiple requests using an if statement, I get the following Error:ReferenceError: getElementById is not defined. I am using a getElementById in my .js file. I cant seem to find a way to use multiple requests for each button, as I am new to express.

math.html

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Calculator</title>
  </head>
  <body>

<h1>Calculator</h1>

    <form action="/math" method="post">

      <input type="text" name="n1" placeholder="First Number" >
      <input type="text" name="n2" placeholder="Second Number" >
      <button type="submit" name="add">+</button>
      <button type="submit" name="subtract">-</button>
      <button type="submit" name="multiply">*</button>
      <button type="submit" name="divide">/</button>

      </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

calculator.js

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get("/math", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/math.html");
});

app.post("/math", function(req, res) {

var num1 = Number(req.body.n1);
var num2 = Number(req.body.n2);

var add = num1 + num2;
var subtract = num1 - num2;
var multiply = num1 * num2;
var divide = num1 / num2;

//create if statements for each button click to add multiply etc...
if(getElementById('button').name="add") {
  res.send("Answer: " + add);
}
if (getElementById('button').name="subtract") {
  res.send("Answer: " + subtract);
}
if (getElementById('button').name="multiply") {
  res.send("Answer: " + multiply);
}
else {
  res.send("Answer: " + divide);
}

});
```

Expected Results: clicking on each math symbol calculates equation.
Actual Results: ReferenceError: getElementById is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've mixed things up.

`getElementById` is a property of the `window` object and it's thus accessible only within the browser context.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

You are trying to access `getElementById` within the NodeJS context, which obviously doesn't contain that reference.

The value you're looking for is probably available within the `req` callback property of express. I haven't tested it though.

Comment: Thank you. changing each if statement to if(req = "add") and so on made each button work.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend sending the data you are looking for through a req body, Which you can achieve by using AJAX on the client side.Once you have sent the req through AJAX you can access it with the dot notation.

a example: req.query.name would grab the name from a HTTP arg with the following link as a example localhost:1234/myapp?name=helloworld!
Or grab whatever you passed with the AJAX post/get

like mentioned above you shouldn't use client side code for back end logic.